# Inherited 2nd Gen Ipod Nano - cannot delete iPod music

Tags: rhythmbox, ipod

I have acquired (legitimately) a 2nd gen ipod nano.  It is full with music not to my taste.  When I open it up in Rhythmbox I am unable to delete the existing iPod music.

Answer (score 0):

One does not simply plug an iPod and expect it work's - unless you're using Mac OS.

It's the same with Windows - there you need iTunes.
When I used an iPod, I used to use `gtkPod` to manage the music on the device.

As far as I know there is a iPod plugin for Rhythmbox already installes (can't tell, using Amarok), have a look at [this](http://ubuntu-install.blogspot.ch/2011/04/connect-ipad-and-ipod-with-ubuntu.html).